# UTF error when reading in GPX files using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gis, gpx

I am trying to take a batch of GPX files and concatenate them into a pandas dataframe to then export as a CSV for analysis elsewhere (QGIS).

Problem is, when I do my list comprehension step, it gives me a UTF-8 encoding error. I took a look at one of the GPX files, and it explicitly declares the encoding at the beginning of the file as expected. Not sure what I am missing. Code and error message below.

CODE

```
INDIR=r'/Path/to/data'
OUTDIR=r'/Path/to/data/out'
os.chdir(INDIR)

def parsegpx(f):
    #Parse a GPX file into a list of dictionaries.  
    
    points2 = []
    with open(f, 'r') as gpxfile:
        # print f
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpxfile)
        for track in gpx.tracks:
            for segment in track.segments:
                for point in segment.points:
                    dict = {'Timestamp' : point.time,
                            'Latitude' : point.latitude,
                            'Longitude' : point.longitude,
                            'Elevation' : point.elevation
                            }
                    points2.append(dict)
    return points2

files = os.listdir(INDIR)
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(parsegpx(f)) for f in files])
```

ERROR

```
<ipython-input-44-408221aa1cb1> in <module>
----> 1 df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(parsegpx(f)) for f in files])
      2 # df2.head(5)

<ipython-input-44-408221aa1cb1> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(parsegpx(f)) for f in files])
      2 # df2.head(5)

<ipython-input-4-8ece4e512e75> in parsegpx(f)
      6     with open(f, 'r') as gpxfile:
      7         # print f
----> 8         gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpxfile)
      9         for track in gpx.tracks:
     10             for segment in track.segments:

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gpxpy/__init__.py in parse(xml_or_file, version)
     35     from . import parser as mod_parser
     36 
---> 37     parser = mod_parser.GPXParser(xml_or_file)
     38 
     39     return parser.parse(version)

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gpxpy/parser.py in __init__(self, xml_or_file)
     68         """
     69         self.xml = ""
---> 70         self.init(xml_or_file)
     71         self.gpx = mod_gpx.GPX()
     72 

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gpxpy/parser.py in init(self, xml_or_file)
     80 
     81         """
---> 82         text = xml_or_file.read() if hasattr(xml_or_file, 'read') else xml_or_file # type: ignore
     83         if isinstance(text, bytes):
     84             text = text.decode()

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 27: invalid start byte
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This means the file is *not* a UTF8 file. You should find out wha the file's codepage is and open it with the corresponding encoding, eg `with open(f, 'r', encoding="latin1")`. If the encoding doesn't match the file you'll get mangled data instead of an error.

Comment: You should probably ask whoever created that file to save it as UTF8.

Comment: Whatever the file may say about its encoding, it isn't UTF-8. That is what the message is telling you. Open the file and count 27 positions into the string it is choking on.  0x87 is a double- dagger symbol in Latin-1. It is unfortunately not unheard of for files to declare themselves as UTF-8 when they are not.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining, that makes more sense now. So if I understand you both correctly, there is a mis-identification of encoding between the code I have written and the file itself? So if I try something like `file -I 15*.gpx`, it should show the actual encoding of the file and then I would adjust my encoding parameter accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use encoding while opening the file.

```
    with open(f, 'r', encoding="desired_encoding") as gpxfile:
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about that but right now unable to comment.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention in my original post that I did try that. My fault. It gives the same error.